# How to plot different domain over the same function

Tags: matlab

```
 x = linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,120);
 x1 = linspace(-pi/6,pi/6,120)
 y = sin(x);
 y1 = sin(x);

   hold on
   plot(x1,y1)
   plot(x,y)
```

How do I plot the sin(x) function over the domain -pi/2 - pi/2 and -pi/6 - pi/6
it only plots the same function as the initial domain but ending at the limit I wanted

Comment: not clear what are you asking. you want to plot the same function on an overlapping range? (-pi/2 to pi/2 contains -pi/6 to pi/6) why?

Comment: Yes so it would look the same but only use x values from -pi/6 to pi/6 on the same function like a small section of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first,  you have a typo you need to write `y1=sin(x1)`
second, you can be more efficient using anonymous functions:

```
y=@(x) sin(x)
```

then you can define the range at will:

```
plot(x,y(x),'x'); hold on
plot(x1,y(x1),'o');
```